# Remove indentation in acronyms list

Tags: glossaries

I'm using the `glossaries`package to create an acronyms list.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage[%
    acronym,
    toc,
    style=long,
    nogroupskip,
    nopostdot,
    nonumberlist,
    nomain,
    section
]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newacronym{BBSR}{BBSR}{Bundesinstitut für Bau-, Stadt- und Raumforschung}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[%
     type=\acronymtype,
     title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

How do I remove the indentation? I tried other styles but did not found an appropriate one. Is there any simple solution?
[image: indentation]

Comment: \setlength{\LTleft}{-5pt} seems to do the trick

Comment: Is there a way to do this more precisely? What are the default margins in a longtable?

Comment: I think it would be easier selecting a different style... http://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/glossaries-styles/